# подготовленный запрос, не работает оператор LIKE и как получить массив результатов

Tags: php, mysqli

Собственно, что я делаю:

```
    <?php
$link=mysqli_connect(DB_LOCAL,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME,DB_PORT);
$stmt=mysqli_prepare($link,'SELECT `id` FROM `notes` WHERE `name` LIKE ? ');
if (isset($_GET['qves'])){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$_GET['qves']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    wtf($id);
    wtf(mysqli_error($link));
} else{
    echo 'Ничего не найдено';
}
wtf($_GET);
?>
```

Две проблемы:

- выводит пустую переменную $id
- как сделать правильно запрос для получения всех столбцов?

Comment: У вас в `$_GET['qves']` - точное совпадение по `name`, или частичное?

Comment: частичное совпадение

Comment: Начнем с того, что никакой массив здесь и не запрашивается

Comment: Еще бы неплохо mysqli_prepare убрать внутрь if, ведь, по сути, если условие не выполняется, то и prepare не нужно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, у вас проблема в запросе. Должно быть так:

```
$search = '%' . $_GET['qves'] . '%';
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s', $search);
```

Оператор `LIKE` можно представить как условие "если значение совпадает с шаблоном ...". У вас получалось "`если значение совпадает с шаблоном qves`" (что, фактически, означает "`поле равно qves`"), в то время, как нужно было "`если значение совпадает с шаблоном [любые символы]qves[любые символы]`". `[любые символы]` в MySQL - оператор `%`.

Для того, чтобы получить все результаты выборки, а не только первый, нужно привести код примерно к такому виду:

```
$link=mysqli_connect(DB_LOCAL,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME,DB_PORT);
$stmt=mysqli_prepare($link,'SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `name` LIKE ? ');
if (isset($_GET['qves'])){
    $search = '%' . $_GET['qves'] . '%';
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s', $search);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        wtf($row);
    }
    wtf(mysqli_error($link));
} else{
    echo 'Ничего не найдено';
}
wtf($_GET);
```

как вы можете увидеть, я избавился от `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id); mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);` потому как они не к месту, если набор извлекаемых полей динамический. В новом варианте в `$row` на каждой итерации будет массив с данными очередного результата выборки.

Comment: так, это понял, но нужно все совпадения мне найти

Comment: что бы получить все столбцы надо, как я понял, по количеству столбцов нужно сюда (mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id);) переменных впихнуть а потом нормальный массив из них сделать, проще никак?

Comment: @Ghost вы в коде берете только одно совпадение. Первое. Хотите перебрать все совпадения - вызывайте `mysqli_stmt_fetch` в цикле. На каждой итерации будет `id` новый. http://www.php.su/mysqli_stmt_fetch Только что значит "столбцов"? Вам кроме `id` нужны другие поля? Укажите их в запросе, а потом в `mysqli_stmt_bind_re‌​sult`. Уточните ваш вопрос и я поправлю ответ.

Comment: Меняем $stmt=mysqli_prepare($link,'SELECT `id` FROM `notes` WHERE `name` LIKE ? ');  на $stmt=mysqli_prepare($link,'SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `name` LIKE ? '); потом по количеству столбцов я должен переменных добавить в mysqli_stmt_bind_result, можно ли как-то их сразу в массив запихнуть что бы запрос был не зависим от таблицы (я таблицы еще собираюсь менять)

Comment: @Ghost дополнил ответ согласно вашему вопросу.